# How to find text inside an array from a json file?

Tags: arrays, node.js, json, fs

I have a json array called "names". I want to prevent repeating the same name by searching it before it is entered on the array.

I find this code, but i need also to run the function `enterName` if the name is not repeated.

Thnaks

```js
var name = "TEST";
                for (var i = 0; i < config.names.length; i++){
                    if (config.names[i] == name){
                        console.log("name repeated");
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
if (!config.names.find(p=>p===name))
  enterName(name);
```

Comment: if (!config.names.find("test")) {
TypeError: test is not a function

Answer (score 0):

Using ES7

```
const name = "TEST";
if (!config.names.includes(name)) {
    enterName(name);
}
```